Why was Abel's sacrifice favored over Cain's?
In the story of Cain & Abel, Cain brings an offering to the Lord from the fruit of the field. On the other hand, Abel offers the firstborn from his livestock. The LORD looks favorably upon Abel and his sacrifice, but not upon Cain and his offering. Why?
The thing that stands out to me, personally, is that while Abel's sacrifice is qualified as being of the firstborn of the flock - Cain's isn't. Cain took the first fruits for himself, and then later brought some of his excess produce as an offering to the Lord - almost like an after thought.
Another idea that I've read about is that since the ground has been cursed, Cain's offering is fundamentally tainted. I'm less convinced by this, however. After all, the curse was that it would require hard work to generate produce - not that the produce itself would be bad. If anything, the extra labor required would if anything seem to make Cain's offering that much more valuable (had he offered the first fruits).
What is taught in Judaism? Is there a predominant interpretation?
